# Реализация умножения матриц. Класс матрица

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Планирую реализацию класса матрицы со всем необходимым набором арифметики. 
Начиная с 59 строчки кода получаю ошибку "выражение должен иметь тип указателя на объект". Что я делаю не так?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <iomanip>

 using namespace std;
 int i;
class Matrix
{
private:

int str, col;
int **mat;

public:

Matrix(int str, int col)
{
    this -> str = str;
    this -> col = col;
    mat = new int*[str];
    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = new int[col];
    }
}   

int & operator [] (int i)
{
    return i;
}


void FillMatrix()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            mat[i][j] = rand() %10;
        }
    }
}

void PrintMatrix()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << mat[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

Matrix mul(Matrix &a, Matrix &b)
{
    Matrix mat(3, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < str; j++)
            {
                mat[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < col; k++)
                {
                    mat[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return mat;
}

~Matrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        delete[] mat[i];
    }
    delete[]mat;
}


};

int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

Matrix a(3, 3);
Matrix b(3, 3);
Matrix c(3, 3);

b.FillMatrix();
a.FillMatrix();

a.PrintMatrix();
b.PrintMatrix();



}
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, нужно разобраться с вопросом перегрузки [][] и вопроса круглых и квадратных скобок? Или это не то направление?)

Comment: Так а что вы ожидали от такого `int & operator [] (int i)`? Написана какая-то бессмыслица.

Answer (score 1):

Недостаток использования оператора **[]** в том, что он принимает только один аргумент и если вы определите его так:

```
int * operator [] (int i){    return mat[i]; }
```

то прога будет работать, *но* второе использование квадратных скобок будет сишным. Первый вызов скобок это будет называться дайте мне адрес элемента строки **i** столбика **0**, а второй вызов скобок пусть Си прибавляет сам адрес и выдаст мне ссылку на элемент. Эта ваша функция вводит в заблуждение и приведёт к большим проблемам.

Правильным способом организовать доступ к элементам будет не оператор, а функция:

```
int & Elt (int str,int col){    return mat[str][col]; }
```

Answer (score 1):

В этом варианте я бы сделал

```
const int * operator [] (size_t i) const
{
    return mat[i];
}
```

и

```
int * operator [] (size_t i)
{
    return mat[i];
}
```

и все. В данном варианте представления матрицы это самое то - не нужны никакие прокси...